KERNEL.BIN not found
I am trying to follow a tutorial about building an operating system, I have used basically the same code as the tutorial person, but running the build on qemu says:
"KERNEL.BIN file not found!"
Here is the C code for reading a FAT12 system:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef uint8_t bool;
#define true 1
#define false 0

typedef struct 
{
    uint8_t BootJumpInstruction[3];
    uint8_t OemIdentifier[8];
    uint16_t BytesPerSector;
    uint8_t SectorsPerCluster;
    uint16_t ReservedSectors;
    uint8_t FatCount;
    uint16_t DirEntryCount;
    uint16_t TotalSectors;
    uint8_t MediaDescriptorType;
    uint16_t SectorsPerFat;
    uint16_t SectorsPerTrack;
    uint16_t Heads;
    uint32_t HiddenSectors;
    uint32_t LargeSectorCount;

    // extended boot record
    uint8_t DriveNumber;
    uint8_t _Reserved;
    uint8_t Signature;
    uint32_t VolumeId;          // serial number, value doesn't matter
    uint8_t VolumeLabel[11];    // 11 bytes, padded with spaces
    uint8_t SystemId[8];

    // ... we don't care about code ...

} __attribute__((packed)) BootSector;

typedef struct 
{
    uint8_t Name[11];
    uint8_t Attributes;
    uint8_t _Reserved;
    uint8_t CreatedTimeTenths;
    uint16_t CreatedTime;
    uint16_t CreatedDate;
    uint16_t AccessedDate;
    uint16_t FirstClusterHigh;
    uint16_t ModifiedTime;
    uint16_t ModifiedDate;
    uint16_t FirstClusterLow;
    uint32_t Size;
} __attribute__((packed)) DirectoryEntry;


BootSector g_BootSector;
uint8_t* g_Fat = NULL;
DirectoryEntry* g_RootDirectory = NULL;
uint32_t g_RootDirectoryEnd;


bool readBootSector(FILE* disk)
{
    return fread(&g_BootSector, sizeof(g_BootSector), 1, disk) > 0;
}

bool readSectors(FILE* disk, uint32_t lba, uint32_t count, void* bufferOut)
{
    bool ok = true;
    ok = ok && (fseek(disk, lba * g_BootSector.BytesPerSector, SEEK_SET) == 0);
    ok = ok && (fread(bufferOut, g_BootSector.BytesPerSector, count, disk) == count);
    return ok;
}

bool readFat(FILE* disk)
{
    g_Fat = (uint8_t*) malloc(g_BootSector.SectorsPerFat * g_BootSector.BytesPerSector);
    return readSectors(disk, g_BootSector.ReservedSectors, g_BootSector.SectorsPerFat, g_Fat);
}

bool readRootDirectory(FILE* disk)
{
    uint32_t lba = g_BootSector.ReservedSectors + g_BootSector.SectorsPerFat * g_BootSector.FatCount;
    uint32_t size = sizeof(DirectoryEntry) * g_BootSector.DirEntryCount;
    uint32_t sectors = (size / g_BootSector.BytesPerSector);
    if (size % g_BootSector.BytesPerSector > 0)
        sectors++;

    g_RootDirectoryEnd = lba + sectors;
    g_RootDirectory = (DirectoryEntry*) malloc(sectors * g_BootSector.BytesPerSector);
    return readSectors(disk, lba, sectors, g_RootDirectory);
}

DirectoryEntry* findFile(const char* name)
{
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < g_BootSector.DirEntryCount; i++)
    {
        if (memcmp(name, g_RootDirectory[i].Name, 11) == 0)
            return &g_RootDirectory[i];
    }

    return NULL;
}

bool readFile(DirectoryEntry* fileEntry, FILE* disk, uint8_t* outputBuffer)
{
    bool ok = true;
    uint16_t currentCluster = fileEntry->FirstClusterLow;

    do {
        uint32_t lba = g_RootDirectoryEnd + (currentCluster - 2) * g_BootSector.SectorsPerCluster;
        ok = ok && readSectors(disk, lba, g_BootSector.SectorsPerCluster, outputBuffer);
        outputBuffer += g_BootSector.SectorsPerCluster * g_BootSector.BytesPerSector;

        uint32_t fatIndex = currentCluster * 3 / 2;
        if (currentCluster % 2 == 0)
            currentCluster = (*(uint16_t*)(g_Fat + fatIndex)) & 0x0FFF;
        else
            currentCluster = (*(uint16_t*)(g_Fat + fatIndex)) >> 4;

    } while (ok && currentCluster < 0x0FF8);

    return ok;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Syntax: %s <disk image> <file name>\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    FILE* disk = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (!disk) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open disk image %s!\n", argv[1]);
        return -1;
    }

    if (!readBootSector(disk)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not read boot sector!\n");
        return -2;
    }

    if (!readFat(disk)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not read FAT!\n");
        free(g_Fat);
        return -3;
    }

    if (!readRootDirectory(disk)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not read FAT!\n");
        free(g_Fat);
        free(g_RootDirectory);
        return -4;
    }

    DirectoryEntry* fileEntry = findFile(argv[2]);
    if (!fileEntry) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find file %s!\n", argv[2]);
        free(g_Fat);
        free(g_RootDirectory);
        return -5;
    }

    uint8_t* buffer = (uint8_t*) malloc(fileEntry->Size + g_BootSector.BytesPerSector);
    if (!readFile(fileEntry, disk, buffer)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not read file %s!\n", argv[2]);
        free(g_Fat);
        free(g_RootDirectory);
        free(buffer);
        return -5;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < fileEntry->Size; i++)
    {
        if (isprint(buffer[i])) fputc(buffer[i], stdout);
        else printf("<%02x>", buffer[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    free(buffer);
    free(g_Fat);
    free(g_RootDirectory);
    return 0;
}

Here is the Makefile code:

ASM=nasm
CC=gcc

SRC_DIR=src
TOOLS_DIR=tools
BUILD_DIR=build

.PHONY: all floppy_image kernel bootloader clean always tools_fat

all: floppy_image tools_fat

#
# Floppy image
#
floppy_image: $(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img

$(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img: bootloader kernel
    dd if=/dev/zero of=$(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img bs=512 count=2880
    mkfs.fat -F 12 -n "PROJECT" $(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img
    dd if=$(BUILD_DIR)/bootloader.bin of=$(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img conv=notrunc
    mcopy -i $(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img $(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.bin "::kernel.bin"
    mcopy -i $(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img test.txt "::test.txt"

#
# Bootloader
#
bootloader: $(BUILD_DIR)/bootloader.bin

$(BUILD_DIR)/bootloader.bin: always
    $(ASM) $(SRC_DIR)/bootloader/boot.asm -f bin -o $(BUILD_DIR)/bootloader.bin

#
# Kernel
#
kernel: $(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.bin

$(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.bin: always
    $(ASM) $(SRC_DIR)/kernel/main.asm -f bin -o $(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.bin

#
# Tools
#
tools_fat: $(BUILD_DIR)/tools/fat
$(BUILD_DIR)/tools/fat: always $(TOOLS_DIR)/fat/fat.c
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)/tools
    $(CC) -g -o $(BUILD_DIR)/tools/fat $(TOOLS_DIR)/fat/fat.c

#
# Always
#
always:
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)

#
# Clean
#
clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)/*

Here is the bootloader code (boot.asm):
org 0x7C00
bits 16

%define ENDL 0x0D, 0x0A

;
; FAT12 Header
;
jmp short start
nop

bdb_oem:            db 'MSWIN4.1'
bdb_bytes_per_sector:   dw 512
bdb_sectors_per_cluster:    db 1
bdb_reserved_sectors:   dw 1
bdb_fat_count:      db 2
bdb_dir_entries_count:  dw 0E0H
bdb_total_sectors:      dw 2880
bdb_media_descriptor_type:  db 0F0h
bdb_sectors_per_fat:  dw 9
bdb_sectors_per_track:    dw 18
bdb_heads:          dw 2
bdb_hidden_sectors:     dd 0
bdb_large_sector_count:     dd 0

; Extended boot record
ebr_drive_number:       db 0
                db 0
ebr_signature:          db 29h
ebr_volume_id:          db 12h, 34h, 56h, 78h
ebr_volume_label:       db 'PROJECT  '
ebr_system_id:          db 'FAT12   '

;
; Code starts here
;
start:
    mov ax, 0
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x7C00

    push es
    push word .after
    retf

.after:
    mov [ebr_drive_number], dl

    mov si, msg_loading
    call puts

    push es
    mov ah, 08h
    int 13h
    jc floppy_error
    pop es

    and cl, 0x3F
    xor ch, ch
    mov [bdb_sectors_per_track], cx
    inc dh
    mov [bdb_heads], dh

    mov ax, [bdb_sectors_per_fat]
    mov bl, [bdb_fat_count]
    xor bh, bh
    mul bx
    add ax, [bdb_reserved_sectors]
    push ax

    mov ax, [bdb_dir_entries_count]
    shl ax, 5
    xor dx, dx
    div word [bdb_bytes_per_sector]
    test dx, dx
    jz .root_dir_after
    inc ax

.root_dir_after:
    mov cl, al
    pop ax
    mov dl, [ebr_drive_number]
    mov bx, buffer
    call disk_read

    xor bx, bx
    mov di, buffer

.search_kernel:
    mov si, file_kernel_bin
    mov cx, 11
    repe cmpsb
    je .found_kernel

    add di, 32
    inc bx
    cmp bx, [bdb_dir_entries_count]
    jl .search_kernel

    jmp kernel_not_found_error

.found_kernel:
    mov ax, [di + 26]
    mov [kernel_cluster], ax

    mov ax, [bdb_reserved_sectors]
    mov bx, buffer
    mov cl, [bdb_sectors_per_fat]
    mov dl, [ebr_drive_number]
    call disk_read

    mov bx, KERNEL_LOAD_SEGMENT
    mov es, bx
    mov bx, KERNEL_LOAD_OFFSET

.load_kernel_loop:
    mov ax, [kernel_cluster]
    add ax, 31
    mov cl, 1
    mov dl, [ebr_drive_number]
    call disk_read
    add bx, [bdb_bytes_per_sector]
    mov ax, [kernel_cluster]
    mov cx, 3
    mul cx
    mov cx, 2
    div cx
    mov si, buffer
    add si, ax
    mov ax, [ds:si]
    or dx, dx
    jz .even

.odd:
    shr ax, 4
    jmp .next_cluster_after

.even:
    and ax, 0x0FFF

.next_cluster_after:
    cmp ax, 0x0FF8
    jae .read_finish

    mov [kernel_cluster], ax
    jmp .load_kernel_loop

.read_finish:
    mov dl, [ebr_drive_number]
    mov ax, KERNEL_LOAD_SEGMENT
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    jmp KERNEL_LOAD_SEGMENT:KERNEL_LOAD_OFFSET
    jmp wait_key_and_reboot

    cli
    hlt

; Prints string on screen
; Parameters:
;   - ds:si points to string
puts:
    push si
    push ax

.loop:
    lodsb
    or al, al
    jz .done

    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov bh, 0
    int 0x10

    jmp .loop

.done:
    pop ax
    pop si
    ret

;
; Error handlers
;

floppy_error:
    mov si, msg_read_failed
    call puts
    jmp wait_key_and_reboot

kernel_not_found_error:
    mov si, msg_kernel_not_found
    call puts
    jmp wait_key_and_reboot

wait_key_and_reboot:
    mov ah, 0
    int 16h
    jmp 0FFFFh:0

.halt:
    cli
    hlt

; Converts an LBA address to a CHS address
; Parameters:
;   - ax: LBA address
; Returns:
;   - cx [bits 0-5]: sector number
;   - cx [bits 6-15]: cylinder
;   - dh: head
lba_to_chs:
    push ax
    push bx
    push dx

    mov bx, [bdb_sectors_per_track]
    xor dx, dx
    div bx
    inc dx
    mov cx, dx

    mov bx, [bdb_heads]
    xor dx, dx
    div bx
    mov dh, dl
    mov ch, al
    shl ah, 6
    or cl, ah

    pop dx
    pop bx
    pop ax
    ret

;
; Reads sectors from a disk
; Parameters:
;   - ax: LBA address
;   - cl: number of sectors to read (up to 128)
;   - dl: drive number
;   - es:bx: memory address where to store read data
;
disk_read:
    push ax
    push bx
    push cx
    push dx
    push di

    push cx
    call lba_to_chs
    pop cx

    mov al, cl
    mov ah, 02h
    mov di, 3
    
.retry_disk_read:
    int 13h
    jc .disk_read_error
    jmp .disk_read_done

.disk_read_error:
    dec di
    jnz .retry_disk_read

    jmp .fail

.fail:
    call disk_reset
    jmp floppy_error

.disk_read_done:
    pop di
    pop dx
    pop cx
    pop bx
    pop ax
    ret

; Resets disk controller
; Parameters:
;   dl: drive number
disk_reset:
    pusha
    mov ah, 0
    stc
    int 13h
    jc floppy_error
    popa
    ret

msg_loading:            db 'Loading...', ENDL, 0
msg_read_failed:        db 'Read from disk failed!', ENDL, 0
msg_kernel_not_found:   db 'KERNEL.BIN file not found!', ENDL, 0
file_kernel_bin:        db 'KERNEL  BIN'
kernel_cluster:         dw 0

KERNEL_LOAD_SEGMENT     equ 0x2000
KERNEL_LOAD_OFFSET      equ 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0AA55h

buffer:


Here is the kernel code (main.asm)
org 0x7C00
bits 16


%define ENDL 0x0D, 0x0A

start:
    ; print hello world message
    mov si, msg_hello
    call puts

.halt:
    cli
    hlt

;Prints string on screen
;Parameters:
;   - ds:si points to string


puts:
    ; save registers we will modify
    push si
    push ax
    push bx


.loop:
    lodsb   ;loads next character in al
    or al, al   ; verify if next character is null
    jz .done
    

    mov ah, 0x0e    ;call bios
    mov bh, 0   ;set page no
    int 0x10

    jmp .loop


.done:
    pop bx
    pop ax
    pop si
    ret



.halt:
    jmp .halt

msg_hello: db 'Hello world from KERNEL!', ENDL, 0


The make command ran without error, so I am very confused. Please help,  I am a beginner in this
I was expecting the system to read the text.txt file and display:
"Hello world from a file!!!"
Edit: Qemu command:
qemu-system-i386 -fda build/main_floppy.img

Please add the qemu command you are giving.  Note that you build the file build/kernel.bin but  qemu is saying it can't find KERNEL.BIN.

Edited it in the post, what should the command be?

Unrelated but the kernel should not use org 0x7c00 since that's the address of your boot sector. KERNEL_LOAD_OFFSET is defined to be 0. Use your debugger to single step the code and see why it does not find the file. The add di, 32 in .search_kernel: is extremely suspicious since the repe cmpsb has already adjusted di so you can't just add 32 to move to the next entry.

FAT filename comparison is case insensitive. That is, KERNEL.BIN and kErNeL.bIn are the same file. You probably need memcasecmp. And, the filename can be stored on the disk as the up/down version. Further, the name is stored without the . The field uint8_t Name[11]; might be better defined as uint8_t Name[8];  uint8_t Ext[3]; The boot is trickier and you may have force a single case stored on disk.

So, the TL;DR is to force a name to uppercase when creating the disk.

forget about case sensitiveness. mcopy knows to uppercase it, image file contains it in uppercase. @Jester is right about kernel's org which should be 0. But more importantly, the bootloader is quite broken and cannot function as it is. Directory search is broken (di corrupted after cmpsb), lba_to_chs is broken (doesn't return everything it promises), disk_read is broken (trumples all over the values that ARE returned from there). With these 4 places fixed, everything works as expected.

The bootloader has one more bug - it ignores FAT cluster size when loading the kernel (assumes cluster and sector are the same). This happens to work for floppies since their cluster size is 1 sector, but would fail for larger images.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
